# C# string.format with decimal format.

Tags: c#, decimal, string.format

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
for (int i = 0; i < drives.Length; i++)
{
    if (drives[i].IsReady)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0} - Has free space of {1} GB",drives[i].ToString(),(drives[i].TotalFreeSpace/1024/1024/1024).ToString("N2"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Drive C:\ - Has free space of 70,00 GB
Drive D:\ - Has free space of 31,00 GB
Drive E:\ - Has free space of 7,00 GB
Drive F:\ - Has free space of 137,00 GB
```

All end up with ,00 but I need to show real size. So which format is suitable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format string doesn't have anything to do with it. Your integer operations are discarding any remainder.

```
3920139012 / 1024 / 1024  / 1024 // 3
```

Specify decimals using the `m` suffix like so:

```
3920139012 / 1024m / 1024m / 1024m // 3.6509139575064182281494140625
```

Alternatively:

```
3920139012 / Math.Pow(1024, 3) // 3.65091395750642
```

This might be a little more clear:

```
var gb = Math.Pow(1024, 3);
foreach(var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{   
    if(drive.IsReady)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0} - Has free space of {1:n2} GB",
            drive.Name,
            drive.TotalFreeSpace / gb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Becasue you are doing *integer division* which truncates decimal remainders.  Use floating-point division instead:

```
drives[i].TotalFreeSpace/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0
```

or

```
drives[i].TotalFreeSpace / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0)
```